# Is there a better way to prevent one ip address from performing an action twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, database, performance

I have a model `Item` that can be voted on by creating a `Vote`. `Vote` has an attribute `:ip` that records the user's ip address. If an Item's array of Votes contains a particular ip, that ip is blocked from creating another Vote.

**models:**

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

**items_controller:**

```
def vote
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  if (!@item.votes.map(&:ip).include? request.remote_ip)
    Vote.create!(ip: request.remote_ip, item_id: @item.id)
  end
end
```

This model isn't that slow right now. But I'm worried about what might happen when I start getting millions of votes. In one instance, I'm fetching a array of every Item that hasn't been voted on by the current ip. As votes increase in number, that would be an insane number of records to look over. Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

One idea I had is the following:

1.) Load an array of Votes with the user's ip: `@votes = Vote.where(ip: request.remote_ip)`

2.) Create an array of the Items (`@items`) associated with these Votes

3.) "Subtract" `@items` from `Item.all` to create a new array `@unvoted_items`

4.) Check if `@unvoted_items` includes the current Item

Would that be a more efficient model? Can anyone think of a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do much simpler:

```
@item.votes.where(ip: request.remote_ip).exists?
```

As long as your votes table has an index on `[:item_id, :ip]` this will be fast.

In addition, you should consider making the index a unique one (or you will be vulnerable to race conditions). Depending on usage pattern you might choose to rely on the unique index:

```
begin
  @item.votes.create!(ip: request.remote_ip, item_id: @item.id)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  # take whatever action is required upon a duplicate entry
end
```

If most inserts are successful then this saves making checks that nearly always succeed.

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism won't work if you have more than one rails server which I assume you will since you mentioned "millions".  The better way is to enforce the restriction of IPs in your db with unique indexes.  It will be far faster to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Following will do a seach in database without retreive all of them;:

```
if Vote.where(item_id: @item.id, ip: request.remote_ip).exists?

end
```

Comment: Would `!@item.votes.where(item_id: @item.id, ip: request.remote_ip).exists?` be any slower for some reason?

Comment: Yes, this one will be the same, the problem in your question was this part @item.votes.map(&:ip), as you will load all votes with all its paramter

Answer (score 1):

All of the current answers require adding conditional logic to your controller. Rails has a built-in way of validating unique database records. Simply add a uniqueness validation on your model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :ip, message: 'has already voted'
```

Now in your controller, you only have to handle two possible outcomes: valid or invalid. Here's an example:

```
def create
  @vote = Vote.new(item_id: @item.id, ip: request.remote_ip)

  if @vote.save
    redirect_to @vote
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

If someone tries to vote twice, `@vote.errors.messages` will look like this:

```
{ ip: ['has already voted'] }
```

These errors are usually displayed in the form.

For more information related to ActiveRecord validations, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html.